# How to use EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS correctly in Doxygen

Tags: c, doxygen

Doxygen version used: 1.8.20

I'm trying to exclude certain functions from the referenced list in HTML documentation (the list is enabled by *REFERENCES_RELATION = YES*).

Code example:

```
void a()
{
    b();
    c();
}

void b()
{
    c();
}

void c()
{
    
}
```

When I generate HTML documentation **without any exclusions**, it appears as expected:

> ```
> a()
> void a    (       )   
> References b(), and c().
>
> b()
> void b    (       )   
> References c().
>
> c()
> void c    (       )
> ```

However, if I add the following: ***EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS        = b***, then the generated HTML is:

> ```
> a()
> void a    (       )   
>
> c()
> void c    (       )
> ```

**b() is excluded as expected, but c() doesn't appear in references list of a().**

How do I make this work?

Comment: You didn't mention the doxygen version you used, but I tried with 1.8.20 and observed the same problem. I would have expected that the relation between `c` and `a` is still shown. Probably worth a bug report at https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/new/choose

Comment: @albert thanks, I'm also using version 1.8.20 (edited question to include this information)
I'll probably open a bug report as you suggested...

Comment: OP created an issue in the doxygen issue tracker: https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/8061